# error: no viable conversion from 'std::__1::__wrap_iter<int *>' to 'int'

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, stl, iterator

Aim of the code is to print "Yes" if the number 'h' is present in v vector and its corresponding index . If the number is not present you have to print "No" followed by the index of the next smallest number just greater than that number.

Thank you for help in advance.

```
    //Code (1) .
    cin >> h; 
    int lower = lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),h);
    if(v[lower] == h) cout<<"Yes ";
    else              cout<<"No ";
    cout << lower+1;
```

By the code(1),the above error is generated ,but the program run successfully when we use Code(2).

```
    //Code (2).
    cin >> h;
    int lower = lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),h) - v.begin();
    if(v[lower] == h) cout<<"Yes ";
    else              cout<<"No ";
    cout << lower+1;
    cout<<endl;
```

What happens different when we substract **v.begin()**.

Comment: Look up what `lower_bound` returns.  If you don't know where to look that up, then you can do so here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/

Comment: @ NathanOliver iI referred couple of website but ,when displaying the lower bound we always use to substract v.begin , i am not getting the reason from same. It would be great if you light over the concept. thanks

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound - look at what it returns; an *iterator*.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl  Yeh , i know that it returns iterator and since 'v.begin()' is also an iterator please help me knowing  what happens different when we substract one iterator with other                   ( lower_bound returned iterator - v.begin())

Comment: Think about edge cases such as an empty container and a return of `end()`. Also read up on [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Answer (score 2):

This expression:

```
lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),h);
```

returns an `iterator` to an element in `v`. Using the result as an index into `v` is not going to give a meaningful result (even if it compiles). Fortunately, the compiler gives an error and doesn't let you do this.

On the other hand, subtracting the `begin` iterator from the result does give an index:

```
lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),h) - v.begin();
```

This value obtained by subtracting 2 iterators is the *distance* between these iterators, which is another way of expressing the index.

Note that this index may still not be valid to use to use with `v`. Consider what happens when `h` is bigger than all the elements in `v`. The index will be equal to `v.size()`, and indexing into `v` at this position is UB.

The correct way to check if the element is found in `v` is to compare with `v.end()`, like this:

```
auto it = lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),h);
if(it != v.end()) 
  cout << "Yes, at index " << std::distance(v.begin(), it);
else
  cout<<"No ";
```

Comment: But when i run Code (2) it run successfully and give proper result.

Comment: It won't if the returned iterator is `v.end()`. Well it's UB, so it might appear to work. Edited the answer to explain that. Also added a better way to find the distance between 2 iterators.

Comment: @ cigien It would be great if you brief me about  UB.

Comment: It's not too complicated. UB means undefined behavior. An example would be using an index that is not within the range of a vector. UB means *anything* can happen, and you can't rely on that. You can't even rely on it to crash your program. If a program has UB, it's wrong, whether it seems to give the right answer or not. See [this] for more details.

Comment: @ cigien Please correct me if I am wrong , Is it UB because when we get the difference  of 'v.end()'  (which is the iterator pointing to next to last element of the container)  and 'v.begin()' , It would be the total **size** of the container , and index should be of maximun **size - 1**.